# JUnit/Selenium: Splitting my class to use the Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

realise this might be a bit of a big ask, but I'm having trouble splitting my test class to use the Page Object Model.

My current class basically works as so:

1. @BeforeClass - **startUp()** Loads properties file for variables and starts ChromeDriverService
2. @Before - **createDriver()** Opens Chrome browser, and navs to homepage
3. @Test - **desktopHappyCallback()** Does some page interaction, then calls:
4. **hideDynamicElements()** Hides some elements on the page
5. **runScreenshotValidation()** Saves a screenshot and compares it by calling:
6. **compareScreen()** Compares and returns a true/false
7. @After - **tearDown()** Quits the ChromeDriver
8. @AfterClass - **stopService()** Kills the ChromeDriverService

The class is currently (*have cut bits out of the methods to make it shorter*):

```
public class desktopHappy {

private static ChromeDriverService service;
private static WebDriver driver;
private static Properties obj = new Properties();

//Set up screenshot comparison via im4java
private static boolean compareScreen(String expectedImage, String currentImage, String diffImage) {
    CompareCmd compare = new CompareCmd();
    compare.setErrorConsumer(StandardStream.STDERR);
    IMOperation comparisonExe = new IMOperation();
    comparisonExe.metric("mae"); //mae = Mean Absolute error (average of all the color differences)
    comparisonExe.addImage(currentImage);
}

//Compare via ImageMajick
private void runScreenshotValidation() throws IOException, InfoException {
    String current = "screenshots\\current\\Current.png";
    boolean compareSuccess = compareScreen(baseline, current, difference); //Run the compare method
    }
}

//Hide dynamic elements on the page (if they exist)
private void hideDynamicElements() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<By> criteria = Arrays.asList(
            By.className("telephone-number"),
            By.cssSelector("#chatContainer"),
    );
    for (By dynamicElement : criteria) { //Loop through the criteria
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(dynamicElement);
        for (WebElement hideElement : elements){ //Loop through each instance of an element
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }
}

@BeforeClass //Pulls in Properties, and starts up the ChromeDriverService before the Tests run
public static void startUp() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream propfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty
            ("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\resources\\config.properties");
    obj.load(propfile);

    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File(obj.getProperty("chromeDriverLoc"))) //Driver set in properties
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
    service.start();
}

@Before //Starts up the Chrome browser (on home page) before each Test
public void createDriver() {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    driver.get(obj.getProperty("targetENV")); //Opens home page (set in properties)
}

@Test //Checks the Callback form (modal)
public void desktopHappyCallback() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#callbackInputPhone")).sendKeys(obj.getProperty("formsPhone"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Request a callback']")).click();
    WebDriverWait waitForSuccessMessage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    waitForSuccessMessage.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
            (By.cssSelector("#callbackForm > div.success-message")));

    hideDynamicElements(); //Run the hide dynamic elements method
    runScreenshotValidation(); //Run the screenshot comparison method
}

@After //Quits the ChromeDriver after each Test
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@AfterClass //Kills the ChromeDriverService at end of Tests
public static void stopService() {
    service.stop();
}}
```

So in IntelliJ I've tried to split up my project with packages as so:

[image: structure]

I've been trying to move into the **baseCompare** class:

- hideDynamicElements()
- compareScreen()
- runScreenshotValidation()

Then into the **baseSetup** class:

- startUp()
- createDriver()
- tearDown()
- stopService()

Then **homePage** will contain my representations and **desktopHappy** will contain my test assertions.

However I'm getting *really* stuck working out how to split things up so that they work together. Is anyone able to give me an example on how I should be splitting things up under these packages? (sorry big ask!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are dividing your logic very fairly.

The only thing that i would change, is to have your `base*` classes under your base package, rather than an actual physical `base` package.

For example:

```
com.salessite/
  baseCompare.java
  baseSetup.java
  basePage.java
  baseTest.java
  pages/
    homePage.java < basePage.java
  tests/
    desktopHappy.java < baseTest.java
```

Also by creating more `base`'s, you give yourself more leeway for future changes.

> so that they work together

IF by work you mean, compile - then you should have no problem.  say for example that `homePage.java extends basePage.java`, then in `homePage.java`, you'd have the appropriate import.

`import com.salessite.basePage;`

Importing is how to access external classes and references. (access modifiers permitting, of course.)

Comment: please keep in mind that Java is a camelCased language yes, but the convention is for all classes to be PascalCased.